# Use imcrop to split an image in half

Tags: matlab

I want to use `imcrop` to split an image in half. However, the result is not exactly half of the picture. What is the problem?

The code is here:

```
I=imread('example.png');
[x,y]=size(I); 
disp(x);
disp(y);
A = imcrop(I, [0 0 x y/2]);
[x1,y1]=size(A);
imshow(A);
```

Any picture can be used as an example.

Comment: I assume this only happens for images with odd-numbered widths, is this right? You can't split a pixel in halfs.

Comment: Thanks! I've learned that it is because in '[x,y]=size(I)', the return value of size() has 3 dimension but I use 2 dimension [x, y] to receive, so the value y is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only request two outputs from `size`, then it will return the true first dimension as the first output and return the product of all other dimensions as the second output. It doesn't care what the actual dimensionality of your data is.

In your case, you have an RGB image, therefore it is recommended that an explicit dimension is specified as the second input to `size`. This will ensure that you get the dimension that you want.

```
nRows = size(I, 1);
nCols = size(I, 2);

A = imcrop(I, [0 0 nRows round(nCols/2)]);
```

In general, I use the dimension input to `size` regularly to ensure that I get exactly the dimension that I want.